# Adding values of an array N times to reach a target

Tags: php, arrays, function

1. I have a target number (maximum capacity of more than one class room)
2. An array of department IDs . 
   `$depts = array(1,2,3);`
3. A function that returns the total number of students taking a particular course from a Department.

   `function noStudentsTakingCourse ($dept_id){
   //Some expressions..
   return $student_count;
   }`
4. An array of capacity of the available rooms, ie, the capacity of class rooms that are vacant
   `$available_room_capacities = array(50, 75, 40, 36, 100, 250);`

What I want is:
From the department IDs, I want each available class room to be assigned a department in which the number of students taking that in the department is greater or equal to the room capacity.

I don't know if you get me, but am fairly new to programming and I've spent days trying to get this without any success.

```
$total_no_of_students_taking_course = 223;
$dept_ids_taking_course = array(1, 2, 3);
$available_room_capacities = array(50, 70, 35, 59, 95, 100);

function noOfStudentsTakingCourse($dept_id)
{
$r = 0;
if ($dept_id == 1) {
    $r = 100;
} elseif ($dept_id == 2) {
    $r = 56;
} elseif ($dept_id == 3) {
    $r == 67;
}

return $r;
}
```

Hers's what i've been able to come up with. all it does is randomly sum values from the class_room array until they're greater than the total number of students taking the course. But, most times it sums more than 5 values when the department here is only 3. i want the case where by:
- Department 1 (with capacity of 100) would be allocated a room greater of equal to 100,
- Department 2 (with capacity of 56) would be allocated a room greater or equal to 56 and so on.

That means the final array would be of lenght 3 and its sum would not be less than 223 (according to the code above)

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Show us your best attempt so far so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Based on what you said it does, it seems odd that `noStudentsTakingCourse()` takes no arguments. How do you specify which course/department?

Comment: Thanks, was a typo..